# Modulus Inequalities Proof: $|x-1|+|x-5| \geq 6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

Need to prove that:
$$|x-1|+|x-5|  \geq 6$$
I've tried squaring but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly?
Thank you in advance

Note: x is real and does not equal 1 or 5

Comment: My guess is thatthe question either should be $\geq 4$, or $|x-1|+|x+5|\geq 6$ or $|x+1|+|x-5|\geq 6$.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for solutions for which $x$ does the following hold?

Comment: Can always do cases.  Not $x-5 < x-1$ so we can do three cases $x-5\ge  0\iff x \ge 5$ and and so $x-1 + x-5 = 2x -6 \ge 10-6 = 4$.  So not always true  If fact $4 \le 2x - 6=|x-1|+|x-5| < 6 \iff 10 \le 2x < 12 \land x \ge 5 \iff 5\le x < 6$.  So is false for $5 \le x < 6$.  for $x-5< 0\le x-1$ or $1\le x < 5$ then $|x-1| + |x-5| = x-1 +5-x = 4 < 6$ so is never true for $1\le x < 5$.  And finally for $x < 1$ then $|x-1| + |x-5| = 5-x+1-x = 6-2x$.  And $6-2x \ge 6 \iff x \le 0$.  So this is true for $x \le 0$ and not true for $0 < x < 6$ and true for $x \ge 6$.

Comment: Argh!  ZOMBIE THREAD!!! ZOMBIE THREAD!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false, since if $x = 2$, $|x - 1| + |x - 5| = 4$, which is less than $6$. If you meant to have $4$ in place of $6$ in your statement, then it would be true by the triangle inequality:

$$|x - 1| + |x - 5| = |x - 1| + |5 - x| \ge |(x - 1) + (5 - x)| = |4| = 4.$$

Comment: I'm fairly sure the question excludes 1 and 5 as options for x though?

Comment: Then take $x = 2$. The expression $|x - 1| + |x - 5|$ will equal $1 + 3 = 4$, which is still less than $6$.

Comment: Indeed, $|x-1|+|x-5|=4$ for any $1\leq x\leq 5$.